# How do I write a regular expression that brings specific characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract a specific string from the inside when the following string exists. The string I want to extract is uuid.

But I don't know how to fill out the regular expression to bring uuid. How can I write it except for '/' and '-' before and after uuid?

```js
const text = "hello_img/2021/12/27/uuid-c.jpg";
const reg = /\b\/u.*?-/g;
const matches = text.match(reg);
  
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Try: `/\bu[^-]+/`

Comment: Are we talking about `uuid` as a string, or will `uuid` be replaces with a real uuid?

Comment: For example, I wrote uuid, which is really uuid. It's probably v3.

Comment: Can you give some concrete examples (with lots of variation)?

Comment: For the uninitiated, as I was until now, "UUID" =  [Universally unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Comment: example: hello_img/2021/12/27/f189f4ae-af11-11e7-b252-186590cec0c1-helloworld.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take text after last occurence of /, that seems to be th uuid that you want:

```
const url = "hello_img/2021/12/27/f189f4ae-af11-11e7-b252-186590cec0c1-helloworld.jpg";
console.log(url.split("/").pop());
```

output will be

```
f189f4ae-af11-11e7-b252-186590cec0c1-helloworld.jpg
```

to remove .jpg, you can use

```
newUrl = url.replace('.jpg','');
```

Comment: thanks. There's a simple way like this, but I think I only thought of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the actual format of the uuid after the last occurrence of the `/` then you can match the `/` and capture the format in capture group 1 followed by matching any char except `/` till the end of the strin.

```
 \/\b([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})\b[^\/\r\n]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GkVj5z/1)

```js
const text = "hello_img/2021/12/27/f189f4ae-af11-11e7-b252-186590cec0c1-helloworld.jpg";
const reg = /\/\b([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})\b[^\/\r\n]*$/;
const m = text.match(reg);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know a good regular meal. Happy New Year!